# Binary search tree performance

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

So, finding a key takes O(height) time, how much time does it take to find all nodes with a key greater than a given key? What are the constant factors?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Please tag it as such. Constant factors are usually determined experimentally in real life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it will be done properly, you would probably find the key, and then go In-Order to the next ones.

So it will be O(logn) + m . Where m is the number of bugs greater than the key.
Worst case would be O(logn) + n = O(n)

Comment: Worst case for finding the key is O(n) -> when the tree is unbranched and just a straight chain. So overall it is O(n) + n = O(n)